# How do I call functions within this code? Im using the visual studio software. keep getting errors that array1 and 2 are undefined

Tags: error-handling

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjnVN.png)

Sorry im new to coding . I have searched up possible solutions for this on here but they didnt work. Im also confused on why some code appears grey compared to the rest.
https://1drv.ms/w/s!Ag8vVFKVPyOg6HeYLehGjQKdvl_3?e=QHY6t9

```
#include <stdio.h>
// initialised variables
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
void displayfunction(void);

int month = 0;
void highervalues(float array1[12], float array2[12]);

void highervalues(float array1[12], float array2[12]) {
    for (i = 12; i > 0; i--) {
        if (array2[i] > array1[i]) {
            count = count + 1;

        
        }
    }
}

//Reading values for array1 and array2
void displayfunction(void) {
    highervalues(array1[12] , array2[12]);
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        
        month = month + 1; // month increases by 1 after each input
        printf_s("enter values for year 1 month %d", month);
        scanf_s("%f", &array1[i]);
    }
    for (month = 12; month > 0; month--) {
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        month = month + 1;
        printf_s("enter values for year 2 month %d", month);
        scanf_s("%f", &array2[i]);
    }

}
/*comapring 2 arrays and increasing count value if there are any value in array2
are greater than array1*/
int main() {
    displayfunction();
    int array1[12];
    int array2[12];
    
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: I added a link if that helps? thanks

Comment: No, a link is even worse. Did you read any of the links I gave you? Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post.

Comment: theres was an error when i tried the first  time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of variable scope

```
int main() {
    displayfunction();
    int array1[12];
    int array2[12];

}
```

Those arrays are only available in main. If you want other functions to operate on them you have to pass them as paramters to those functions. Plus they dont exist at the point where you try to call displayFunction

So change

```
void displayfunction(void)
```

to

```
void displayfunction(float array1[12], float array2[12])
```

then in main do

```
int main() {
   int a1[12];
    int a2[12];
    displayfunction(a1, a2);
}
```

Note that I have changed the names here just to emphasise that its the not the fact that the names are the same thats important.

Comment: thanks. So is there anyway to call the higher sales function in the displayfunction?

Comment: @Sam21 you already did that correctly